# Do I need all the node modules for running a simple APP in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I am starting to learn the angular i started with the angular starting tutorial and checked added few bootstrap dependencies to it. After successfully ran my application(which is simple TODO), I noticed that the node_module size. Which is around 360MB. So my question is do I need all those modules to run the application, and do the all the modules are trusted?

**EDIT:** Thanks All, for your response, for starter like me i think I need to stop worry about this time. I think I need to get back to this after I learned complete angular(and developed few applications). But I found this link where it shows the graph info of the angular@cli http://npm.anvaka.com/#/view/2d/%2540angular%252Fcli
Thanks again I marking this a closed, topic is too broad to explain/answer.

Comment: Node modules will always be heavy. But once built, your application can be very light. Tree shaking will remove all the unused JS code for you, don't worry. You can probably remove some modules, but since you're startign to learn, I wouldn't advise it.

Comment: 360MB is huge. Way more than it should be. It would take me 8 minutes for me to download that at full speed, to put some meaning into this number. The node_modules folder may be large, but only the resulting js file matters.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to check the AOT : https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler.

`ng serve --aot`

`ng build --aot`

It will take only part of each modules to optimize the size.